# Проблема с русскими символами в json

Tags: android, json

Реализую поиск по таблице Mysql с андроида.При загрузке json результата поиска,русские символы отображаются в виде знаков вопроса,с английскими все нормально.Также при отправке POST-запроса для поиска,не понимает русские символы.

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

Context c;
String data;
ListView lv;

ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();


public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.data = data;
    this.lv = lv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    if(integer==1)
    {
        //BIND TO LISTVIEW
        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private int parse()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jo;

        names.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String id=jo.getString("id");
            String name=jo.getString("name");
            String price=jo.getString("price");
            names.add(id);
            names.add(name);
            names.add(price);

        }

        return 1;


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

}

```
public class DataPackager {

String query;

public DataPackager(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public String packageData()
{
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    StringBuffer queryString=new StringBuffer();

    try
    {
        jo.put("Query",query);


        Boolean firstValue=true;
        Iterator it=jo.keys();

        do {
            String key=it.next().toString();
            String value=jo.get(key).toString();

            if(firstValue)
            {
                firstValue=false;
            }else {
                queryString.append("&");
            }

            queryString.append(URLEncoder.encode(key,"UTF-8"));
            queryString.append("=");
            queryString.append(URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));


        }while (it.hasNext());

        return queryString.toString();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

}

```
public class SenderReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

Context c;
String urlAddress;
String query;
ListView lv;
ImageView noDataImg,noNetworkImg;

ProgressDialog pd;

public SenderReceiver(Context c, String urlAddress, String query, ListView lv,ImageView...imageViews) {
    this.c = c;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.query = query;
    this.lv = lv;

    this.noDataImg=imageViews[0];
    this.noNetworkImg=imageViews[1];
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(c, R.style.MyTheme);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.sendAndReceive();
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    pd.dismiss();

    //RESET LISTVIEW
    lv.setAdapter(null);

    if(s != null)
    {
        if(!s.contains("null"))
        {
            Parser p=new Parser(c,s,lv);
            p.execute();

            noNetworkImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            noDataImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else
        {
            noNetworkImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            noDataImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }else {
        noNetworkImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noDataImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


}

private String sendAndReceive()
{
    HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
    if(con==null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        OutputStream os=con.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
        bw.write(new DataPackager(query).packageData());

        bw.flush();

        //RELEASE RES
        bw.close();
        os.close();

        //SOME RESPONSE ????
        int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

        //DECODE
        if(responseCode==con.HTTP_OK)
        {
            //RETURN SOME DATA stream
            InputStream is=con.getInputStream();

            //READ IT
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();

            if(br != null)
            {
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line+"\n");
                }

            }else {
                return null;
            }

            return response.toString();


        }else {
            return String.valueOf(responseCode);
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PHP

```
 $con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
  echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name=$_POST['Query'];
$sql = "SELECT id,name,price FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($query)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $data[]=$row;
  }
    echo(json_encode($data));
}else
{
  echo('Not Found ');
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: А у вас бд хранит данные в utf8?

Comment: Да,кодировка utf8_general_ci

Comment: А заголовок, отсылаемый по заходу на страницу какой? (В том смысле - какой формат там указан)

Comment: Вы про URL?или в самом файле PHP